# How I can change Firefox tab color with a new WebExtensions add-on?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to make a new WebExtensions add-on to change the color of my tab but I didn't find anything applicable. [`tabs.insertCss()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) can be used only to change CSS inside tab content, but can not style the tab bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do so right now.

Longer: An API is being worked on which will allow some *limited* changes to the browser UI, which *might* include what you desire. The API, `browser.theme.update()`, currently exists in Nightly (Firefox 55). It used to be behind a preference, but is now enabled by default. This API does *not* permit you to insert arbitrary CSS. You will only be able to change the things specifically included in the API. Inserting arbitrary CSS is something that explicitly *won't* be permitted.

See:

- Blog post announcement: [Improving Themes in Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/02/24/improving-themes-in-firefox/)
- [Beginning of a thread on dev-addons](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-addons/2017-February/002604.html)
- [Continuing that dev-addons thread a month later](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-addons/2017-March/002664.html)
- [Main tracking bug for all feature development related the new theming API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1330328)

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for all your information. Do you know what's the status on being able to modify the color of (not all but) a specific tab in the tab bar currently ? The thread you have linked hasn't received any update for four years.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be the ability to do what you want (i.e. color a specific tab in the tab bar). You can change the color for things like the selected tab, which your extension could do dynamically when a new tab is selected, but it doesn't appear that there's a way to color specific tabs. You can read through the documentation for [`browser.theme.update()`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme/update), which points to the documentation for [manifest.json:theme](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/theme).